# Interação entre formulários?

Tags: c#, winforms

No meu programa, eu inseri um botão e um `panel`. Quando o botão é clicado, a lógica insere outro formulário no `panel` sobrepondo o `form` inicial.

No `form2` que aparece tem um botão retornar, que faz com que o `form2` suma e reapareça o `form1`, porém nenhum código que tento usar está dando certo. O código do botão é o seguinte:

```
//FORMULÁRIO CONTEUDO

this.panel1.Controls.Clear();
Conteudo frm = new Conteudo();
frm.TopLevel = false;

panel1.Controls.Add(frm);
frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
panel1.Height = this.Size.Height;
panel1.Width = this.Size.Width;
frm.Size = new Size(this.panel1.Width, this.panel1.Size.Height);
Application.DoEvents();
frm.Location = new Point(0 + this.panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X, 0 + this.panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
panel1.BringToFront();
panel1.Visible = true;
panel1.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
frm.Show();
```

E no `form2`, no botão, eu utilizei o seguinte código, e outras tantas variantes:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.Controls.Clear();
this.Close();
frm.Refresh();
```

Se puderem me ajudar, eu realmente agradeço muito. A parte de abrir o formulário está funcionando, mas o botão de retornar ao `form1` não funciona, quando consigo, utilizando o código acima, o formulário 1 fica apenas branco.

Comment: Disse que está usando [tag:webforms], correto? Esse `Form` se refere ao `<form runat="server">`? Ou algo diferente que criaste?

Comment: Desculpe o erro @brazilianldsjaguar , eu estou utilizando windowsforms (visual studio). Parece que a pergunta foi editada.

Comment: Poderia postar um print dos dois formulários, e como gostaria que ocorressem as transições.

Answer (score 1):

//Pra chamar um form simplesmente faça.

```
protected void btnChamaForm2_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Form2 form2 = new Form2();
  form2.show();

  //e fecha o form atual assim
  this.visible = false; ou this.Clos();
}
```

//Para retornar para o Form1, faça a mesma coisa.

```
protected void btnRetornar_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form1 form1 = new Form1();
   form1.show();

   //fecha o form atual.
   this.visible = false; ou this.Clos();
}

protected void btnRetornar_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form1 form1 = new Form1();
   form1.show();

   //fecha o form atual.
   this.visible = false; ou this.Clos();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assim Bruno, aparentemente você está limpando os controls do Form2, acredito que seja isso que está deixando o formulário em branco, e você não precisa instanciar novamente o formulário pois quando você clica no botão o this já é o formulário, no método no controlador você tem que receber como parametros isso:

```
protected void btnRetornar_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.Close();
}
```

se você der um refresh no novo formulário instaciado ele irá aparecer novamente em branco porque você removeu as controls dele, tente fazer somente o básico acima.

Comment: Continuou branco o fundo, porem, meu programa esta funcionando como uma "árvore", existe o form inicial, e para manter o menu dele nas laterais, inseri o form2 dentro do control do form inicial, assim, ao clicar num botão abre o form2 dentro do form1, como dois em um só, quando é clicado um certo botão no form2 ele abre um terceiro form, neste que contém o botão de retornar, no qual não consigo fazer ele voltar ao form2, imagino que aja conflito de controles entre os formularios. Obrigado pela ajuda @Thiago Falcão

Answer (score 0):

Bruno, no botão do form1 que chama o form2 você coloca o código:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Já no botão que fecha o Form2 e retorna para o Form1 você pode por o seguinte código.

```
//não há a necessidade de instanciar novamente o Form2 pois ele já foi instanciado.
this.Close(); // que ele limpa automaticamente os controles. mas pode usar o clear também se preferir.
```

Answer (score 0):

Para abrir o form2 faça o seguinte:

```
//Limpe o form atual da forma que está fazendo

//Crie uma instância de Form2
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
//Exiba o form2
form2.ShowDialog();
//Verifica se o form foi fechado
if(form2.IsDisposed)
{
    //Código para montar o form anterior
    //Acredito ser o primeiro bloco de código que você postou.
}
```

Para voltar do form2 para o form1 faça o seguinte:

```
protected void btnRetornar_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Também pode utilizar a variavél `DialogResult` [msdn:dialogResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx)